# Google map crashes on zooming out firefox19

Tags: firefox, google-maps-api-3, hardware-acceleration

We have used Google Map API V3 in our application and seemed to have found a strange problem, which is not reproducible on all machines.
The following is the configuration of the machine where we could reproduce it :
OS : Windows7
Graphic Card : 128MB (I guess this should be enough, because I feel the issue is related to these parameters.)

When Zooming out from Google maps in our application we get the following error from Firefox 19 and it crashes completely:l

AdapterVendorID: 0x8086, AdapterDeviceID: 0x 166GL Context? GL Context+ GL Layers? GL Layers+ xpcom_runtime_abort(###!!! ABORT: Framebuffer not complete – error 0x8cd6, mFBOTextureTarget 0xde1, aRect.width 4736, aRect.height 1967: file /builds/slave/rel-m-rel-osx64_bld-0000000000/build/gfx/layers/opengl/LayerManagerOGL.cpp, line 1446)
ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}

After looking out for a similar issue on Google we found that on turning off the hardware acceleration, the maps no more crash.
However this is not a viable solution in our case, since we have a website and we cannot ask every user to turn hardware acceleration off.

Can anybody think of some possible reasons as to why Firefox crashes while zooming out from Google maps in our application? What does hardware acceleration exactly try to do?

Please let me know if any further information is required.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You're seeing this on Windows?  This should only be showing up in the OpenGL codepaths, which aren't normally used on Windows.  Have you changed your hardware acceleration settings to force OpenGL use?

Answer (score 0):

It's just started crashing for me, but it seems to only happen if I'm using Open GL. If I turn it off, it works fine ... so far!